# looping the CACLS function in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, cacls

I would like to lock a series of file from my staff so they can not delete them i have thus compiled a script wich puts the CACLS function into a loop. however this is not taking effect.

could somebody please explain why?

```
FOR /F %%i IN (c:\file.txt) DO CACLS %%i /p :n /y
```

I have been able to narrow it down to the /y at the end how can i continue to Automate the yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong.

Firstly you haven't specified a user/group that you want to apply the permissions to

Example

```
CACLS %%i /p Everyone:n /y
```

Secondly, there is no `/y` switch for `cacls`. If you want to automatically say `y` to the confirmation you can use this

```
echo y| CACLS %%i /p Everyone:n /y
```

So your full batch file would look similar to this

```
FOR /F %%i IN (c:\file.txt) DO echo y| CACLS %%i /p Everyone:n
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah this helps if I change the y| to j| and the Everyone:n to iedereen:n for a dutch windows version (sucks whish that thre would be a language independent method)